# how to use integer variable as subscript in Django template

Tags: django, templates

I have a for loop in a Django template:

```
{% for i in no_of_lift_series_range %}
    {{ workout.lifts.series.i.activity_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

where this fails to output anything. The problem lies in the use of `i`. I know this, because this:

```
{% for i in no_of_lift_series_range %}
    {{ workout.lifts.series.0.activity_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

outputs what it is supposed to output. Why can't I use `i` in the way I want and how do I make this work?

Comment: Why can't you just iterate through `workout.lifts.series`?

Comment: You could also use the `forloop.counter0` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I need i for other purposes in the loop

Comment: Then as Phillip says, use `forloop.counter0`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just out of curiosity, why doesn't it work like I've written in the question?

Comment: @Sandi Because "i" is not a property in the object "workout.lifts.series".  See this: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Comment: @wm3ndez Yes, but what about this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables 
The docs say it does a numeric index lookup on the third attempt, so it should do `workout.lifts.series[i]` after failing both the dictionary and attribute method lookups, right?

Comment: To update, `forloop.counter0` cannot be used since I need `i` in order to do numeric index acces with it, which doesn't seem possible in django templates

Comment: @Sandi you have to think about "i" as a String, as a literal.  When you say {{ object.0 }} Django tries to do: getattr(object, "0") and if it fails it tries to do this: object[int("0")].  But your variable "i" will be interpreted as getattr(object, "i"), it'll look for that name, not it's content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to get the list item by index:

```
@register.filter
def get_by_index(mylist, index):
    return mylist[index]
```

You could use it like this:

```
{% for i in no_of_lift_series_range %}
    {% with item=workout.lifts.series|get_by_index:i %}
        {{ item.activity_name }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your logic seems a bit off. Perhaps you should be doing something like this instead:

```
{% for activity in workout.lifts.series %}
    {% with forloop.counter as count %}
        {{ count }} - {{ activity.activity_name }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor  %}
```