# templates variables in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to use  template variable to access templates dictionaries
when I do {{ pair_name.8 }} it works

but {% with xx=8  %}{{ pair_name.xx }}{% endwith %} doestnt work, please help

Comment: Django templates deliberately do not implement such "subscripting", to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the template. Your view should "prepare" the data in a more accessible manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to use template variable to access templates dictionaries.

The Django template language is deliberately restricted to prevent subscripting, function calls (with parameters), etc. This is to discourage people from writing business logic in the template.

You can implement a [custom template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214376/67579) to perform a subscript lookup, or work with the [*Jinja* template engine](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/switching/#django). But probably a more elegant way to do this is to alter the view, and prepare the logic in a more accessible way.

For example if you need the `xx`-th item, in the view, you perform a mapping with:

```
def some_view(request):
    pair_names = []  # some data
    xx = 8
    data = [pair_name[xx] for pair_name in pair_names]
    context = {'pair_names': data}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Processing this in the view is not only more elegant, but often more efficient as well, since the template engine often is less efficient in walking through data structures.

Answer (score 0):

@Peace Bytheway - Just my 2 cents-  Templates should be as dumb as possible which means try and avoid heavy logic from your template into the view. Ideally, you should also keep the view lightweight. Not much processing. The concept behind the view is to simply delegate. So, separating responsibilities into the right layer is very crucial.